# On my monitor: there is a live bug between the glass and the pixels crawling around

Tags: display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I safely fix my walking “dead pixel” bug?](https://superuser.com/questions/112921/how-could-i-safely-fix-my-walking-dead-pixel-bug)

There is a bug behind the display on my monitor, **how do I get it out**? if it dies while being on the screen I'll be stuck with it hiding about 4 pixels.

It's quite bizarre watching it crawl about on the monitor. I need for it to go away. Can I kill it, is it possible to get the dead bug body out in case it dies in there?

The screen is an old Apple Cinema 20".

[Walking dead pixel](https://superuser.com/questions/112921/how-could-i-safely-fix-my-walking-dead-pixel-bug)

Comment: What sort of monitor? Laptop? Standalone? LCD? CRT?

Comment: arf, it's a apple cinema screen.

Comment: One my friend had a similar issue with Asus laptop. It was even more weird because the laptop had detachable glass above the LCD panel, but the bug somehow intruded the space between the LCD panel itself (i.e. another layer of glass, non-detachable and hermetically sealed to its base) and, of course, died there. Vendor replaced the panel under warranty, through.

Comment: Your best bet would be to take it to Apple and see if they are willing to fix it. As far as I can see Apple Cinema Screens are quite expensive and I wouldn't mess with it because LCDs can be easily damaged. If you really don't want to call Apple, here'sa link  to help you start your search: http://www.ehow.com/how_5859035_disassemble-apple-cinema-display.html You didn't say which version you have so good luck. I've heard (it's unconfirmed) that some Apple displays have actual glass over LCD which could be easily removed. If that's the case then you're in luck. Otherwise look at question 112921

Comment: Oh no my friend. This is what happens when you don't debug.

Comment: A previous Super User question about the same problem ( [walking "dead pixel" bug](http://superuser.com/questions/112921/how-could-i-safely-fix-my-walking-dead-pixel-bug) ) suggests if the bug dies, it might stay where it is, or it might fall out of view to the bottom of the screen after a while.

Comment: At least you have a live screen saver! Can't you kill it with a (very) small pressure and "shake" the screen until it fall on some side? Anyways, I think if you kill it in a corner for example and wait, it will get dry and fall with time. How much time it have been there? Maybe it goes the same way it arrived...

Comment: Duplicate Question :) http://superuser.com/questions/76153/how-to-remove-dead-thunderflies-from-an-lcd-monitor/76239#76239

Comment: @Bavi_H if you reply your answer instead I will accept your answer and close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Bugs/flies/insects are usually attracted to light.

I suggest putting it in a dark room with one bright spotlight. Leave the bug to his own devices.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is possible, you might try compressed air.  I don't know if you can get the air to the bug, and I'd be careful to try to avoid killing / squishing the bug with the air, but it might move the bug or convince him (or her) of the error of his (or her) ways.