# How do I remove something that's stuck in my laptop's screen?

Tags: laptop, display, dead-pixel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove dead Thunderflies from an LCD monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/76153/how-to-remove-dead-thunderflies-from-an-lcd-monitor)

I have Dell laptop with a matte screen under warranty.

A bug has crawled under the glass/plastic(?) on my screen. It was crawling around so I put the laptop on standby, cleaned screen and after I turned it on, the insect wasn't moving any longer - it is dead probably and looks like dead pixel.

How do I remove it??

Comment: Try with a wet tissue (water only) to moister the insect. It may take a while, but water proved to be the best laptop screen cleaner for me.

Comment: Identical question http://superuser.com/questions/76153/how-to-remove-dead-thunderflies-from-an-lcd-monitor

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical way for end-users to remove dead thrips/thunderflies from the inner layers of LCD screens where they like to get lost and die.